# Не отображается объект на сцене. Unity 2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть определенный объект (монстр), со своими скриптами, он двигается, атакует, умирает. Создал я с него префаб, простым перетаскиванием в папку с префабами. 
Сдублировал такого же монстра из префаба, и поставил его в другое место. 
Но как только запускаю игру, он перестает отображаться. (При этом, с первым монстром все ОК). В окне #Scene  вижу что он двигается, еще он может и атаковать, но визуально его нет.

Unity 4.5.1 f3
Кто подскажет, в чем я допускаю ошибку? Спасибо.

Comment: Для получения сколько-нибудь точного ответа, я думаю, что вам стоит указать версию вашего Unity3D, т.к. в некоторых её версиях наблюдались определенные баги, а что-то вообще отказывалось работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно у вас на персонаже есть анимация которая выставляет его ровно в ту же точку в которой он выставлен в префабе на сцене. поэтому вы видите двух монстров как одного. В иерархии на сцене он присутсвует?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/60263)

Comment: Спасибо. Скорее всего так и есть. Сейчас буду разбираться.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я с вами не согласен. По своему опыту, именно так большинство проблем с префабами и возникает. Когда каким либо образом они визуально не видны, а на сцене присутствуют из-за того что настройки префаба располагает его не в то место куда ожидается.